# Japanese Anthy(ibus) not working for Skype 2.2 Beta?

Tags: 11.04, skype, ibus, input, japanese

I've been looking around for a fix to the Japanese Anthy(ibus) fix for Skype 2.2 beta for a few days now and I've been unable to find a fix for it. I'm a new user of Linux and my current setup is Ubuntu 11.04.

So far the only programs that I have tried Anthy with and worked are Firefox, Gedit and Empathy.

I came across this link which was similar to my case but different in terms of distro http://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=613
I have tried the fix but it didn't seem to fix the issue.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix it or the slightest info on what to update/get please feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Moved from a deleted answer: Problem still exists in v4. -- maybe refreshing the question or mod-closing it to re-ask it on present version?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but if you update your Skype Client to version 4.0, maybe your problem will be solved!

http://skype.com/intl/de/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/

Answer (score 0):

```
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus

export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus

export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus

sudo apt-get install qtconfig
#run qtconfig
~$sudo qtconfig
choose input method = ibus -> save

start skype
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This answer would benefit substantially, if you were to edit it to add some explanation (or at least to tell the user exactly *what to do* with these lines).